# USB C Charging Stopped When Xubuntu 20.04 Boots

Tags: 20.04, usb, xubuntu, battery, usb-c

When I have my HP (Elitebook 830 G6) turned off and plugged in via the USB-C port, everything is fine: It charges.

As soon as I turn the laptop on and the process passes GRUB it immediateley stops charging.

I tried plugging int the laptop while in the OS, it first charges, but randomly stops charging.

The system:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux kernel 5.4.0-89-generic #100-Ubuntu SMP Fri Sep 24 14:50:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tried booting off a USB drive (not plugged in the USB-C but the USB-A ;) with Xubuntu 20.04 -> same behaviour. Then I tried Xubuntu 21.10 -> same behaviour.

This all indicates a hardware problem. But I don't understand why the laptop would charge perfectly fine, when the computer is turned off.

Thanks!

* EDIT * I booted 21.10 not 20.10! Fixed above :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, with new USB Type-C laptops, the operating system can control the charging behaviour.

Comment: Hmmmmmm pity >:)

Comment: @Rinzwind So you also think it's a OS or kernel level problem?

Comment: Booted 21.10 not 20.10, sorry for the mistake :)

Comment: I'm afraid it's a Ubuntu issue, it's just to identify where in the stack it is (so long as other OSes, such as Windows, charge the laptop). It might also be the case that Ubuntu wrongly disables the charge indicator (which is certainly possible) but the laptop is still charging.

Comment: The idea for the OS to control the charging behaviour is to let the OS decide when to start charging when the device is hooked up to AC power for a long time. This allows the OS to alleviate any damage to the battery for prolonged charging.

Comment: Now that's a detailed and professional response, thanks @galexite ! I am in the process of filing a launchpad bug against the linux package (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug). As soon as that's done, I will put the link here :)

Comment: You will need to identify your power delivery controller make and model, EC and system firmware versions, as that will identify the driver responsible.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to do that? Or should I just wait for the folks in launchpad to ask for specific commands to be run?